# Permission denied (publickey) on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I know there are already many questions about this but none of them fixes my problem.
I'm trying to connect my ubuntu to my localhost which runs windows10. However, it gave me this error.

username@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).

I tried to use ssh-keygen to create keys on both my ubuntu and windows. That didn't work.
I guessed it has something to do with authorized_key file but I couldn't find that file in .ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Authorized keys are stored in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file (hidden). Or if not there you can find where your keys are stored in: /etc/ssh/sshd_config

It should say somewhere at the top of the file in a comment (#)

You can also see if you can find the cause of the disagreement in the auth.log file when trying to connect:

/var/log/auth.log